# What's the difference between _string_ and -n _string_ in bash conditional expression?

Tags: bash

The *Bash Reference Manual* says that

> [ *string* ]

and

> [ -n *string* ]

will both return *true* if the *string* 's length is not 0

but the fact is not as so

```
greet=

if [ $greet ]; then
    echo '1'
else 
    echo '2'
fi

if [ -n $greet ]; then
    echo '1'
else
    echo '2'
fi
```

the output is
2
1

the *Bash Reference Manual* just says

```
-n string  
string  

True if the length of string is non-zero.
```

so, what the real difference between the two form?

Comment: Note that non-zero does not mean "*length* is not zero". Non-zero could also mean that its numerical value is not zero, which is quite different.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen but the reference manual says explicitly "True if **the length of string** is non-zero"   check this link [http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @user1502952 said, you need to use double-quotes; but let me explain *why*. Suppose you execute:

```
greet=
[ -n $greet ] && echo "it's nonblank"
```

When the shell parses the `[ -n $greet ]` part, it expands `$greet` to the empty string, and then does word splitting. For instance, if `$greet` expanded to something with spaces in the middle, it would treat each "word" as a separate argument to the `[` command. In this case, however, `$greet` expands to nothing, which contains no "word"s at all, and hence is treated as zero arguments to `[` -- it effectively vanishes from the command. So `[ -n $greet ]` is equivalent to `[ -n ]`, which *checks to see if the string "-n" is nonblank*. It is, so it evaluates to true.

Compare this with `[ -n "$greet" ]`: in this case, the double-quotes allow the expansion of `$greet`, but prevent word splitting. So the `[` command actually gets a zero-length second argument, realizes that `-n` is supposed to be an operator, and gets the expected answer.

Answer (score 1):

when you are using -n option, it is required to use double quotes.

```
 if [ -n "$greet" ]
```

as the string is empty the above expression evaluates to false, as the length is zero.

```
 if [ "$greet" ]
```

this also evaluates to false as the string is empty.

Moreover to check for empty string, -z option can be used.

```
if [ -z "$greet" ]
```

this will be true as the string is empty.

Check this link too: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html

Comment: you're wrong. In ``[ ]`` you must always quote variables. This one will print no: ``greet='5 = 7' && [ $greet ] && echo yes || echo no``

Comment: @Aleks-DanielJakimenko, Pls check the link, says it is unsafe to use -n option without double quotes.

Comment: I'm telling you that test command is unsafe without double quotes, it doesn't matter if you use -n option or not. Always use quotes

Comment: @Aleks-DanielJakimenko, Ok thanks got your point, hope i have corrected that.

Comment: @Aleks-DanielJakimenko: Technically, you're all wrong, when you say thing like "you *always* have to use quotes". It's all related to how variable expansion works. Quotation is there to make sure that the variable is processed as a *single argument*. `$emptyvar` will produce *nothing*, not even an argument. If you *know* that the variable is a single word, no special characters, then skipping quotes is perfectly safe (but yes, why would you worry about it... just quote all the time). and yes, `[[` is an exception, variables inside it work in a different way.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath you should quote it even if you assume that the variable is safe. There are several reasons for that. First one is that you shouldn't ever trust the source of the data. Who knows, maybe one day it will give you different output (due to updates or bugs). Especially if user is able to interact with this data! The only reason not to quote is if you expect it to be expanded (if you rely on this functionality). This leads us to another reason to quote variables: when looking at unquoted variables other developers will think that this part of the code relies on expansion.

Comment: @Aleks-DanielJakimenko: that's style guide and best practice. all I wanted to point out that it's not mandated by the language. that's why I said "Technically".

Answer (score 0):

Bash performs word splitting inside `[` but not inside `[[`, so you don't have to quote parameters if you use `[[`:

```
$ x=
$ [ -n $x ]; echo $?; [ -n "$x" ]; echo $?
0
1
$ [[ -n $x ]]; echo $?; [[ -n "$x" ]]; echo $?
1
1
```

`type` shows `[[ $x ]]` as `[[ -n $x ]]`:

```
$ f() { [[ $x ]]; }; type f
f is a function
f ()
{
    [[ -n $x ]]
}
```